# Link div to external url

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I want my div to be clickable and link to an external url. Why doesn't this work or what should I do instead?

html:

```
 <div id="logo_left">
   <a href="..external url.."></a>
 </div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#logo_left {
  //stylestuff
}
#logo_left a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width:  100%;
}
```

Comment: What you really need is some content in your A tag.  An image, some text - something that tells the user what the link actually does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take only the `<a>` and make it into a `display: block;`

```
a.block { display: block; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/cBKzs/1/)**

---

Alternatively, if you are using `<!doctype html>`, you could wrap the div inside an `<a>` and have it clickable that way.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/cBKzs/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event on the on click property of div

```
 <

div id="logo_left" onclick="window.redirect=..external url..">
     </div>
```

Comment: Really not needed. html5 specs allow for `<a><div></div></a>`

Comment: HAs this question been tagged as html5.. Hv we suddenly stopped supporting all other http versions.. This is nuts!

Comment: Perhaps, but even without html5, there are still better, non-javascript solutions.

Comment: Again please point that out as a better answer or a solution and the author of the question can take a call on what soon he wants to use.. N

Comment: Yes, however it's like suggesting to use regex to parse html, it's possible, yes, but it's not recommended and shouldn't be used as html parsers available will do a much better job. Same here, as a thumb rule, where JavaScript can be avoided (easily), it should be.

Comment: Can you please post a solution instead of commenting on others answers and what you think is rig or wrong bat it..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to link to a specific URL just use the complete address starting from http:

```
<div id="logo_left">
   <a href="http://www.external-url.com"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to add size to the `div`, or it will have a `height` and `width` of 0px, and not be visible.